# Rust: the same code compiles with warning or fails with error

Tags: rust

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.philippflenker.com/hecto-chapter-2/) on Windows with

```
D:\src\rust\hecto>cargo --version
cargo 1.57.0 (b2e52d7ca 2021-10-21)

D:\src\rust\hecto>rustc --version
rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
```

I'm having following code in 2 project directories:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;

fn die(e: std::io::Error) {
    panic!(e);
}

fn main() {
    let ctrl_q = 'q' as u8 & 0b1_1111;

    for b in io::stdin().bytes() {
        match b {
            Ok(b) => {
                let c = b as char;
                if c.is_control() {
                    println!("{:#b} \r", b);
                }
                else {
                    println!("{:?} ({})\r", b, c);
                }
                if b == ctrl_q {
                    break;
                }
            },
            Err(err) => die(err),
        }
    }
}
```

After deleting `target` and `Cargo.lock`, in one project I'm getting following output:

```
C:\temp\hecto-tutorial-die-on-input-error>cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.8.5
   Compiling smallvec v1.7.0
   Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling instant v0.1.12
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.5
   Compiling crossterm_winapi v0.9.0
   Compiling parking_lot v0.11.2
   Compiling crossterm v0.22.1
   Compiling hecto v0.1.0 (C:\temp\hecto-tutorial-die-on-input-error)
warning: panic message is not a string literal
 --> src\main.rs:5:12
  |
5 |     panic!(e);
  |            ^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(non_fmt_panics)]` on by default
  = note: this usage of panic!() is deprecated; it will be a hard error in Rust 2021
  = note: for more information, see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2021/panic-macro-consistency.html>
help: add a "{}" format string to Display the message
  |
5 |     panic!("{}", e);
  |            +++++
help: or use std::panic::panic_any instead
  |
5 |     std::panic::panic_any(e);
  |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

warning: `hecto` (bin "hecto") generated 1 warning
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 13.22s
```

while in the other I'm getting

```
D:\src\rust\hecto>cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.8.5
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
   Compiling smallvec v1.7.0
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling instant v0.1.12
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.5
   Compiling crossterm_winapi v0.9.0
   Compiling parking_lot v0.11.2
   Compiling crossterm v0.22.1
   Compiling hecto v0.1.0 (D:\src\rust\hecto)
error: format argument must be a string literal
 --> src\main.rs:5:12
  |
5 |     panic!(e);
  |            ^
  |
help: you might be missing a string literal to format with
  |
5 |     panic!("{}", e);
  |            +++++

error: could not compile `hecto` due to previous error
```

Any idea why it compiles fine in one but fails in the other project?

Comment: I only have one Rust version installed on my machine - `1.57.0` as shown at the beginning.

Comment: Do they have different `edition` values in in `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: Hm, yes, `2018` and `2021`.

Comment: Try setting them to the same value, I bet that's your answer. As the first warning states: `note: this usage of panic!() is deprecated; it will be a hard error in Rust 2021`.

Comment: I didn't expect the compiler to produce different warnings/errors depending on such an entry that looks like the current year. Especially as in the tutorial not even a warning was mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour of the `panic!` macro changed a bit with the Rust 2021 edition, to make it more consistent with other format family macros. [An entire chapter of the migration guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/panic-macro-consistency.html) is dedicated to this.

The fix, and the link with the detailed information is also indicated in the error message you get:

```rust
  = note: `#[warn(non_fmt_panics)]` on by default
  = note: this usage of panic!() is deprecated; it will be a hard error in Rust 2021
  = note: for more information, see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2021/panic-macro-consistency.html>
help: add a "{}" format string to Display the message
  |
5 |     panic!("{}", e);
  |            +++++
help: or use std::panic::panic_any instead
  |
5 |     std::panic::panic_any(e);
  |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```